# What's the correct way to handle SystemCallErrors in Ruby IO?

Tags: ruby, error-handling, io

In Ruby, I can write `contents` to a file at `path` as simply as:

```
IO.write path, contents, :mode => 'w+'
```

However, the documentation does not specify what kind of exceptions may be raised. In C, if a program encounters `EAGAIN` or `EINTR`, it usually tries to write to the file again. Are we supposed to do the same in Ruby (by catching `Errno::EINTR` and `Errno::EAGAIN`)? I would kinda expect there to be a higher-level abstraction in a language like Ruby. What is the correct pattern to use here?

(on the same note, do we have to worry about short counts in Ruby?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging, I found (as expected) that Ruby handles short counts and `EAGAIN` automatically. The appropriate code is [in io.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/io.c#L1156).